# Why in preprocessing image data, we need to do zero-centered data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

Why in preprocessing image data for a neural network, we need to zero-centered data. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Note that this is specific to neural networks. For other machine learning techniques this might not be useful at all. And in general for computer vision (the other tag you added) zero-centering could be disastrous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Mean-subtraction** or **zero-centering** is a common pre-processing technique that involves *subtracting mean from each of the data point* to make it zero-centered. Consider a case where inputs to a neuron are all positive or all negative. In that case the *gradient* calculated during back propagation will either be positive or negative (of the same sign as inputs). And hence parameter updates are only restricted to specific directions which in turn will make it *difficult to converge*. As a result, the gradient updates go too far in different directions which makes *optimization harder*. Many algorithms show better performances when the dataset is *symmetric* (with a zero-mean).

Comment: So the gradient which you mention is dL/dw= f' (wi xi ) xi ?

and if all inputs are all positive, means dL/dW will result a large number?

Comment: Yes, the gradient on loss w.r.t individual weights dL/dw (referring to notation from the page: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5580/how-is-gradient-calculated-for-middle-layer-weights)

Comment: No problem! Btw, here are few references: 1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211436/why-normalize-images-by-subtracting-datasets-image-mean-instead-of-the-current 2) https://www.quora.com/What-is-zero-centering-data-preprocessing-technique 3) https://forums.fast.ai/t/images-normalization/4058